# How to add negative vertical space after `align*` environment?

Tags: align, vertical-spacing, vspace

How can I add a vertical negative space *immediately* after an `align*` environment?

The following attempt does not work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
a&=b \\ &= c
\end{align*}
\vspace{-10mm}%
This is a test.

\end{document}
```

Comment: By default, LaTeX inserts whitespace in the amount of `\abovedisplayskip` and `\belowdisplayskip`, resp., above and below an `align`-type environment. (The default value of both skips is `12pt plus 3pt minus 9pt`.)  It would be helpful if you explained your use case for wanting to allocate less than the default amount of whitespace after an `align*` environment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an *indirect* answer to your query. Instead of brute-forcing your way with `\vspace*` instructions, I suggest you switch from an `align*` setup to a combined `equation*`/`aligned` setup. As long as the line that immediately precedes the displayed equations isn't too long (read: no longer than about `0.4\textwidth`), TeX will *automatically* insert less vertical whitespace both above and below the `equation*` setup than it will with the `align*` setup.

In the following screenshot, the upper half displays the `align*`-based outcome, while the lower half displays the `equation*`/`aligned` outcome. The framelines denote the edges of the textblock.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,showframe}

\begin{document}

\null
\noindent
This is a test. This is a test.
\begin{align*}
a&=b \\ &= c
\end{align*}
This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test.

\bigskip
\noindent
This is a test. This is a test.
\begin{equation*} \begin{aligned}
a&=b \\ &= c
\end{aligned} \end{equation*}
This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test.

\end{document}
```

Comment: This does happen, but this seems like a bug in the `align` environment. I would think that the `align*`and `equation*` environments would behave the same way, particularly if there is only one equation within them.

Comment: @karlh - Why would this be a bug? It's a well-documented feature that has been around for decades. If anything, it provides yet another good example for why it's not a good idea to use `align`-type environments as generic substributes for `equation`-like environments.

Comment: Could you point me to where that is documented? I don't see it in the AMS math documentation (which I've looked over many, many times in the last two decades or so), and it seems illogical to me that the first line of a math display would look different with equation than with align, gather, and so forth. I have noticed this bug...I mean...unanticipated feature before, but it did not occur to me that it was a difference between how equation and how align/gather/etc. work. Good to know.

Comment: @karlh align supports page breaking (so is like longtable) unlike aligned in equation (which is like `tabular`) so like `longtable`  it is always a full width alignment that spans the full page with no surrounding box. That allows page breaking but means it is always full width so `\abovedisplayshortskip` never kicks in (changing that is very non trivial)

Answer (score 4):

Your vskip worked but applies after `This is a test` as you can see if you add more text, the  second line is backed up before the first, overprinting the math.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\showoutput
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
a&=b \\ &= c
\end{align*}
\vspace{-10mm}%
This is a test.
This is a test.
This is a test.
This is a test.
This is a test.
This is a test.
This is a test.
This is a test.
This is a test.
This is a test.

\end{document}
```

You almost always want to leave a blank line before `\vspace` so it acts at the point it is added, not after the following line break.

Comment: But is it possible to add a vertical space immediately after an `align` environment?

Comment: @Colas simplest is to do that with a blank line before vspace as I said. Otherwise don't add vspace just locally change `\belowdisplayskip`